# Import CSV on Maatwebsite / Laravel Excel 3.1 using Excel::import

Tags: php, laravel, maatwebsite-excel, laravel-excel

I've upgraded Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel to 3.1 from 2.1. Some of the method are deprecated.

Here is the code on version 2.1.

```
$data = Excel::load($path, function($reader) {})->get()->toArray();
```

It's working when I used 2.1 but after I upgraded, it's error

> Call to undefined method Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::load()

For version 3.1, i tried to change to

```
$data = Excel::import($path, function($reader) {})->get()->toArray();
```

I know this probably not the correct syntax.

Here my full code when developing using 2.1.

```
$path = $request->file('csv_file')->getRealPath();

    if ($request->has('header')) {
        $data = Excel::import($path, function($reader) {})->get()->toArray();
    } else {
        $data = array_map('str_getcsv', file($path));
    }

    if (count($data) > 0) {
        if ($request->has('header')) {
            $csv_header_fields = [];
            foreach ($data[0] as $key => $value) {
                $csv_header_fields[] = $key;
            }
        }
        $csv_data = array_slice($data, 0, 8);

        $csv_data_file = CsvData::create([
            'csv_filename' => $request->file('csv_file')->getClientOriginalName(),
            'csv_header' => $request->has('header'),
            'csv_data' => json_encode($data)
        ]);
    } else {
        return redirect()->back();
    }

    return view('import.import_field', compact( 'csv_header_fields', 'csv_data', 'csv_data_file'));
```

How to fix this error on version 3.1?

Comment: the thing that bothers me the most is that the vendor map is in dutch sorry just my opinion

Comment: What do you mean @Eningly? Everything is in English, except for "Maatwebsite" because that happens to be the Dutch name of the company that developed the package.

Answer (score 7):

Actually there is no need to create any extra classes for the Excel import in Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel version 3. Basically you can do the whole CSV to array conversion almost in a same way as in version 2:

```
    $path = $request->file('csv_file')->getRealPath();
    $data = \Excel::toArray('', $path, null, \Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::TSV)[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of the `import()` method is not the path to the file anymore in 3.1, but the class name of the Import file you have to create.

In this import file you can define how you want to read the sheet, and to what format you want to convert it, for example a model or a collection.

The easiest way to migrate from 2.1 to 3.1 is to create such an Import class by running (in your case):

```
php artisan make:import CsvDataImport
```

If you want to read all to rows at once, as in your question's code, you could use the `ToCollection` Concern in your import file:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;

class CsvDataImport implements ToCollection
{
    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
        // Use the $rows collection to create your CsvData model.
    }
}
```

In your Controller you can call the import like this:

```
use App\Imports\CsvDataImport;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel;    

Excel::import(new CsvDataImport, $path);
```

You can read more about importing to a collection [here](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/collection.html)

Answer (score 0):

Do Not get back to downgrade, you can easily use new updated version(**"maatwebsite/excel": "~3.1.0"**) with easiest import method.

Update Your Composer.json..

```
 "require": {
    **"maatwebsite/excel": "~3.1.0"**
},
```

### Steps To Use New Version..

- Create Import to run this command in cmd

`php artisan make:import UsersImport`

- It will Create Import in app\imports\UserImport.php

  ```
  <?php
  namespace App\Imports;

  use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
  use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;
  use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;

  class UserImport implements ToCollection,WithHeadingRow
  {

  public function collection(Collection $rows)
  {

      return $rows;

  }

  // headingRow function is use for specific row heading in your xls file
  public function headingRow(): int
  {
      return 3;
  }
  }
  ?>
  ```
- In Your Controller file..

  ```
   use Excel;

  public function importExcel(Request $request) {

   $import = new UsersImport();
   $data = \Excel::import($import, request()->file('import_file'));

   }
  ```

Comment: But How to get file Data in array